# Old versions Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

Does anyone know an archive of older Internet Explorer versions?

I need to update a Windows XP machine and IE6 crashes on Windows Update, so I'd like to try installing IE7 or IE8. I've only found some dodgy download sites which don't look legit.

Preferably Dutch versions (since the OS is Dutch) but English will work fine too.

Thanks!

Comment: If you set windows update to Auto or download and ask to install you will get updates without using the browser. You will get a popup in the system tray. No need to do it using the browser. If I remember right IE8 will not work for windows updates either.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know an archive of older Internet Explorer versions?

You can download it directly from Microsoft [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/C/0/CC0BD555-33DD-411E-936B-73AC6F95AE11/IE8-WindowsXP-x86-ENU.exe), I found this link, by visiting this link [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=261544)

The Dutch version of Internet Explorer 8 is located [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/7/7/777F0C67-5404-4420-890A-2F517022F4C0/IE8-WindowsXP-x86-DEU.exe)

Source: [Microsoft at it again. Playing with IE8 download for XP](https://msfn.org/board/topic/172103-microsoft-at-it-again-playing-with-ie8-download-for-xp/)